# Add search function or tag filter to user page

Tags: feature-request

I just searched for a specific question which I asked on Stack Overflow centuries ago. I noticed that there is no search function or tag filter.

[image]

You can only filter for views, newest, activity and votes.

I had to search every single page until I found the question I searched for.

It would be helpful if I could filter for tags or search your own questions/answers, e.g. if I would be able to filter for "PHP" then I would find the question way faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already can so I don't think we need another place to do this.

To search for questions use the top search bar:

[image]

In your case you would replace `[vb.net]` with `[php]`. For answers replace `is:q` with `is:a`.

When searching you can also click *Advanced Search Tips* to the right:

[image]